# find command not available in GRUB 2 terminal

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2

I went through [this document of gparted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem). Under the heading *Fixing GRUB boot problem* it mentioned using `find` command. But I don't find the command when I run.
While booting my Ubuntu 13.04, in GRUB 2 menu I pressed 'c' to enter GRUB 2 terminal. There when I run `find`, it doesn't recognize the command but the document uses this command.

Answer (score 2):

The gparted document assumes you are using GRUB, not GRUB 2.

In GRUB 2, `find` has been renamed to `search` ([see manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#search)).